# How can I install Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS using legacy boot?

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, uefi, minecraft

I am trying to get a small server running for Minecraft. However, The PC I am using only supports legacy boot, so I cannot boot from my install drive. Is there a way around this? Or is it possible to use an older version and then upgrade from there? I don't know if that last bit is a thing, but I figured I'd ask... :)

A swift reply would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Is the computer not capable of booting from USB? Perhaps by sharing the brand and model of computer (or hardware specs if it’s a desktop system) it may be possible to offer some suggestions 

Comment: The computer is capable of booting from USB. I've booted from other USBs. Specs are a random gateway/intel motherboard, intel pentium 4 (2003) and like 3-4 gigs of ram

Comment: I also haven't been able to find any bios updates, and I did change a setting for usb boot because it seemed like that was UEFI-like, but that didn't fix anything

Comment: An Intel Pentium 4 from circa 2003 would be a 32-bit processor. You will need to find a 32-bit OS, which Ubuntu 20.04 is not. While not supported on this site, I would *strongly* suggest [the legacy Bodhi Linux 5.1 release](https://www.bodhilinux.com/download/), which is built on Ubuntu 18.04. It is capable of running on the hardware you would like to repurpose 

Comment: This^^^ and your system has nothing to do with UEFI. "Legacy USB support" is something that you might have seen in your settings (not the "legacy mode" AKA CSM AKA "BIOS" that is a feature in most UEFI to allow installation of OSes without support). .

Answer (score 0):

Keep the USB boot settings to UEFI

Then download [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/)

and try to burn the USB in **MBR** partition scheme and **BIOS & UEFI** as Target system in rufus.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!